# Magento 2 Display only root category in navigation with subcategories dropdown

Tags: php, magento

I have Magento 2.1.7 website. I just want to display a root category in navigation and all  other subcategories as sub menu of root category. So what do I need to do this?

Comment: Create subcategory under root category then create sub categories under it

Comment: I have created subcategories under root category but i want to display only root category with sub categories as dropdown

Comment: Create new sub category under default root category and move alll your categories under It

Comment: I am talking about frontend view

Comment: give me the url of site